# Convert SQL Server XML data type to string connecting via OleDb

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am connecting to a SQL Server 2008 database using `OleDbConnection`. I am returning one column as an `XML` data type. I need this converted into a standard string type so I can store it in a string variable. When I call `ToString()` all I get is `System.Byte[]`. If I use the `System.Text.Encoding` class all I get is 2 odd characters.

I have tried an `ExecuteScalar`, `SqlDataAdapter`, `SqlDataReader`, and `DataTable`. All give me the same results.

I can't change the connection type or the data type.

I am using a c# Script Task in SSIS. Although this should not matter.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT CAST(XMLFIELD AS NVARCHAR(2048)) AS XMLFIELD FROM TABLE`?

Comment: From the DB table or the datatable in C#? I can't change the query in the DB. Although the I guess I could use a select from my datatable in C#. Although I am not sure of the syntax.

Comment: Maybe if you showed some code it would be obvious why you can't change the query.

Comment: "It shouldn't matter" but it *is* a code smell. Is there a reason for this design choice?

Comment: It is a Stored Procedure. I can only call it, not modify it, and get back the XML data type as a result. If I try any of the above ways to get the column all I can get is System.Byte[].

Comment: Sorry, is there a reason you use a script component as the source and not the `OLE DB Source` component?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your design, you have a Script Component acting as the source for a Data Flow. You have some query in there that is pulling back an xml data type. Unless you have a reason to use a script component source, save yourself the meta data management headache and use an `OLE DB Source` component

Using the following query to simulate your input

```
SELECT
    CAST(D.le_xml AS xml) AS le_xml
FROM
(    
    SELECT
        Element.name
    FROM
        sys.all_columns AS Element
    FOR   
        XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
) D (le_xml);
```

This generates some XML. The abbreviated version looks like on my database.

```
<Element>
  <name>CostCenterCD</name>
</Element>
<Element>
  <name>CostCenterKEY</name>
</Element>
```

This leads me to a package like

[image]

The meta data coming out of the OLE DB Source is `DT_NTEXT`. The TSQL equivalent data type is `nvarchar(max)` for 2005+ systems.

If you know the XML is going to be small, you can use a Derived Column to convert it to a non LOB string. If you don't want Unicode, I find I have better luck going DT_NTEXT to DT_TEXT in one Derived Column and then DT_TEXT to DT_STR. Otherwise, your conversion route is DT_NTEXT to DT_WSTR but you have an upper bound of 4k bytes for that column.